# How many is "(s)"?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

While adding tags to my preferred tags I saw that the "fullmetal-alchemist" tag was apparently used "s" times:
[image: an image of the anomaly]
From the pattern established by the other tags in the drop down menu I know that "(s)" was supposed to be the number if times the tag has been used. **My question is:**
What's going on, and if it's a bug, how is it fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`s` means that it is a tag synonym. You can see more info about what tag synonyms are [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

That tag is a synonym of [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series), you can see that it is a synonym of that [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/fma-series/synonyms), in this part of page:

[image: Synonym list]

Comment: Excellent answer!